# How to write the query for this requirement?

Tags: django, django-models

**I have several hundred thousand svn commit record in my django database, each record save the related info of each commit(like BugID,LinesChanged,SubmitWeek ...)**

[image: Field List]

**I want to summary each field info of the records and create the report according to the SubmitWeek field like the following :**

[image: Statistics]

**I iterate the records and operate the related field value currently , I want to know if there is a more succinct way to define the query and extract the summary? Many thanks**

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague.

If you are looking for a way to form your queries more specific to make Django do more joins and less separate queries, have a look at:

- `values()` and `values_list()` of the QueryManager

If you want to make Django fetch related objects at once and not in separate queries, have a look at:

- `prefetch_related()` and `select_related()`

If you want to update data more efficiently, have a look at:

- `F()` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F

Comment: thanks, my main requirement is that if I run the query and return the  queryset (may be 1000 records) , any method to get the sum result of the specific integer field (like LinesChanged), or define the query to get the sum result  directly?

Answer (score 0):

refer to the manual , I used the following statements and it seems works well , thanks Risadinha anyway :)

```
# Sum all the records's LinesChanged value
SVN_Commit.objects.filter(my filter).aggregate(Sum('LinesChanged'))

# Get the unique SubmitWeek List
SVN_Commit.objects.filter(my filter).values_list('SubmitWeek', flat=True).order_by('SubmitWeek').distinct()
```